# What's the appropriate word for someone that's leaving something?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What's the most appropriate word for someone that's leaving something (or somewhere)? For example, if someone leaves an association permanently, what do I call him?

The term will be used in a software library to denote processes separated from the cluster.

Comment: If he leaves the room he's *gone*.

Comment: True, my example was misleading, not quite what I was looking for. Updated to better clarify my intents.

Comment: Then why did you accept essentially the same answer?

Comment: See: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/245627/whats-the-appropriate-word-for-someone-thats-leaving-something/245630?noredirect=1#comment-531898

Comment: I was about to say "departed" untill i saw it in the question

Comment: It was added by @ScotM after it was answered. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If he has already left, he is *[gone](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gone)*:

> adjective
>
> [PREDICATIVE]  1 No longer present; departed:

If you are not using a predicative expression, *[absent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/absent)* might work better:

> 1. Not present in a place, at an occasion, or as part of something:

For a more permanent departure, *[parted](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/part?q=parted#part__22)*:

> [NO OBJECT]
>   2. (also be parted) Leave someone’s company:

or if you are willing to risk the connotations of death, *[departed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/departed)*:

> adjective
>
> Dead:

*ODO*

Comment: I think _absent_ close to the word I'm looking for, but it denotes, IMO, a temporary situation. If someone leaves an association permanently, what do I call him?

Comment: @EdMelo: If this is not really the answer you are looking for, you should probably remove the green check, so that others are motivated to search as well.

Comment: I accepted the answer because I'm satisfied with the term _departed_. I will be used in a software library to denote processes _departed_ from the cluster. Thanks.

Comment: Good enough. I was just getting ready to offer that as a seperate answer, but I will include it in this one in stead.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context, three other words come to mind to describe a person departing from and organization:

*[Retired](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retired)* has strong connotations of concluding a career, but it also has a general sense of departure:

> : withdrawn from one's position or occupation
>
> : having concluded one's working or professional career
>
> *Merriam-Webster*

*[Dismissed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dismiss?q=dismissed)* has a connotation of forced exit, but can also speak of permitted departure:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
> 1 Order or allow to leave; send away:

*[Fired](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fire?q=fired#fire__17)* clearly communicates an unsavory departure:

> informal Dismiss (an employee) from a job:
>
> *ODO*

Answer (score 1):

You could say "leaver", although I've only heard the term in the context of those who abandon school: school-leavers. And it's exactly what the Cambridge dictionary cites.

"Departed" seems good enough for me in this situation too, even though it's usually used for people who have died.

The Free Dictionary even cites a phrase with the term leaver:

> A merchant ship which breaks off from a convoy to proceed to a different destination and becomes independent. Also called convoy leaver. See also leaver convoy; leaver section.

Other synonyms mentioned there are: "goer" and "departer".

And "departed" doesn't look like as a synonym from the definitions given there.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/departer

Comment: I confess to have never seen the term _leaver_ before. In the context you provided, all I've known was the term _school dropout_.

Comment: I believe school dropout is the american term. The Cambridge dictionary puts UK under "school-leaver". http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/school-leaver?q=leaver

Comment: It's straying a little from the topic of the question, but in the UK "school-leaver" is a common term for anyone who is finishing their school career, with no connotation of dropping out early.

Comment: It is a neutral connotation than? Or could it be used as pejorative term. (Thx for the heads up btw.)